# Seeking quarternary watershed map of Eastern Ontario?

Tags: data, layers, watershed, canada

I am looking for a quarternary watershed map of Eastern Ontario.

Where is the best place to look for this?

I am currently using the ArcGIS Online basemap software to create my maps. I have a CSV file with the watersheds of Eastern Ontario and their geographical polygon boundaries but arcGIS online cannot read it.

Comment: If it is open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: They are already in ArcGIS online > https://services2.arcgis.com/vJlmDE1PmdTcJF0N/arcgis/rest/services/Eastern_Ontario_Watershed_Quarternary/FeatureServer/0 Map> http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=https://services2.arcgis.com/vJlmDE1PmdTcJF0N/ArcGIS/rest/services/Eastern_Ontario_Watershed_Quarternary/FeatureServer/0&source=sd

Answer (score 1):

You may download a shapefile of the quaternary watersheds for most of the province (James Bay/Hudson Bay watershed looks to be excluded) from LIO:

https://www.javacoeapp.lrc.gov.on.ca/geonetwork/srv/en/main.home?uuid=7a99025f-b894-4b8c-97c4-60f830fa1acc

There are a number of good resources there, which you can download and use in your own GIS. I'm not familiar with how one makes maps with ArcGIS Online (I use QGIS because I'm not at a point where my need can justify paying for a license), so I can't tell you whether this will work for you or not. You could always just use QGIS to make your map, though.